# FreeBSD FreeTDS PHP 7 issues. How to connect php to freeTDS

Tags: php, sql-server, unix, server, freetds

I have been banging my head against the wall for the last 6 hours. 
I have a FreeBSD 10 server with PHP 7 installed. 
Using the commands is `isql -v DSN 'USERNAME' 'PASS'` I can login to my remote MSSQL server and run commands.
I installed PHP with PKG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it wasn't configured at runtime and wasn't compiled, use..

Pkg install php.7.odbc